Have quarto find the jupyter kernel within Visual Studio Code
Description
I am trying to follow this vscode tutorial  in the quarto.org site.
The tutorial uses a document hello.qmd whose content can be copied from the same tutorial. We need to edit the hello.qmd to indicate the jupyter kernel we will be using. Let us assume it is my_kernel, we change the header to be:
---
title: "Quarto Basics"
format:
  html:
    code-fold: true
jupyter: my_kernel
---

Now, the trick is to have quarto find the kernel my_kernel. If I just try to preview the document (with the quarto extension installed as indicated in the tutorial), I get the following type of error:
ERROR: Jupyter kernel my_kernel not found. Known kernels: python3. Run 'quarto check jupyter' with your python environment activated to check python version used. 

Then if I run quarto check jupyter I get:
Jupyter is not available in this Python installation.

The issue seems that quarto preview is run within the base conda environment. In the mentioned tutorial, we are instructed to install jupyter in this base environment. However, I don't want to install anything in that base environment (I never do it). Does anyone know of an easy way to indicate the conda environment to be used, the one associated with the kernel for running the code in the qmd file?
I know the question might be more related with VS Code settings, but any help is appreciated. Thanks!
[Note: In my case, I am running VS Code from within WSL (by using the remote VSCode connection WSL:Ubuntu)].

I tried many things and found one possible solution, to avoid installing jupyter in the base conda environment is as follows:
In order to have VS Code use the conda environment where jupyter is installed (other than the default base environment) we can  make VS Code automatically pick up our preferred environment everytime we open up a new terminal, as explained here. This is done as follows:
In the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), I select "Preferences: Open Workspace Settings", then go to the Extensions section on the left, select Python, and then edit the "Default Interpreter" path to point to the python executable used by my environment. In Linux, we can find the later by activating the environment and then running which python:
conda activate my_environment
which python

which, in my case, indicates something like:
/home/my_user/miniconda3/envs/my_environment/bin/python

